# How to show $\mathbb{S}^{2n-1}$ is a $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ bundle over $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ then $n=1,2$ or divisible by $4$?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I was asked to show
if $$\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n}$$ holds. Then $n=1,2$ or divisible by $4$. The $n=1,2$ cases in the converse are verfied. I am wondering how to prove the second claim.

The thought is to use the relationship $$\pi_{j}(\mathbb{S}^{n})=\pi_{j}(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\oplus \pi_{j-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$$as the exact sequence splits. We can use Serre's result which asserts $\pi_{i}(\mathbb{S}^{j})$ are all finite except in the case $i=j,i=4k-1,j=2k$. If we let $j=2n-1$, then we have: $$\pi_{2n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n})=\pi_{2n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\oplus \pi_{2n-2}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$$Since the middle group is $\mathbb{Z}$, this only holds if $n$ is even. But I cannot prove $n$ must be divisible by $4$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the $n = 1, 2$ cases are trivial"; that sounds to me like you're proving the converse.

Comment: Maybe I should edit as "...trivial to verify". But I feel everyone should understand it given the context. I doubt if the converse is true.

Comment: Thinking for a few second I realized I made a mistake. Need to edit...

Comment: No, I still don't understand what you mean by that. You're trying to prove a claim of the form "if $P(n)$ then $n \in S$" where $P$ is a condition and $S$ is a set. What do you mean by "the case $n \in S_0 \subset S$ is trivial"? What case is this?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I am trying to prove if $P(n)$ is true, then $n\in S$. I checked for $n=1,2\in S$, $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: That doesn't prove any case of the statement you're trying to show. It proves cases of the converse.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I see. Probably a new edit is needed.

Comment: It now seems there might be a typo in the statement. The instructor does not remember if $n$ needs to be divisible by 4. So the question remains unclear.